# How to programmatically send tokens using EOSJS safely?

Tags: eosjs

According to the EOSJS readme:

> Using the JsSignatureProvider in the browser is not secure and should
>   only be used for development purposes. Use a secure vault outside of
>   the context of the webpage to ensure security when signing
>   transactions in production
>
> ```
> const defaultPrivateKey =
> "5JtUScZK2XEp3g9gh7F8bwtPTRAkASmNrrftmx4AxDKD5K4zDnr"; // bob const
> signatureProvider = new JsSignatureProvider([defaultPrivateKey]);
> ```

According to this description, `JsSignatureProvider` is not safe to use in combination with .env variables. What is the safe way to programmatically send EOSIO tokens using EOSJS?

Answer (score 1):

`transact()` with the flag `sign: false` returns serializedTransaction binary. You can sign it with independant and safer way you make. For example, make separated signing server which accepts binary and returns it with signature, but not possible to access from outside of your private network.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this article about eosjs and scatter, I think that it has good explanation about signing transactions without exposing your keys using scatter. To be honest, I have never used it but I am planning to.

https://medium.com/coinmonks/dapp-development-on-eos-blockchain-using-eosjs-and-scatter-557f1b5b65d0

Comment: Maybe you misunderstood. Programmatically means to do things using code, not an user interface.